# Restrict su - user for a user having public-private key pair

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, public-key, private-key

We have a user named user_root in our Linux environment. For which we have created the key-pair in AWS. This is our root user and our administrators log in with this username and the ppk file. We don't want to share it with the other teams. When somebody logs in with their AD credentials on the server and tries to do su - user_root, it allows the same. We want to restrict this. We don't want our AD users to switch to user_root user. Please guide!

Answer (score 1):

Shared accounts with privilege are not a good thing. You should have everyone log in with their own credentials to their own accounts (preferably using keys/certs) and then you should have them use [sudo](https://www.sudo.ws/). This way you can have more control over who has what permissions and you have more chance to see what they did.

Comment: We give AD credentials to the users other than administrators to login to the servers. But now the issue that we are facing is - after login to the server with their AD credentials, the users can simply use su - user_root command and switch to user_root and then can get sudo access. This is what we want to block. We don't want AD users to turn to user_root as it is our root account [having aws key-pair].